# Date format not working properly in Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am working on Android application in which I am saving and getting date from ORMLITE. I am using SimpleDateFormat for the formatting of the desire date, but except this pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` it is not formatting it. My current date from server with desired dates with code is given below:

```
try {//EEEE , MMMM dd , yyyy hh:mm a
                SimpleDateFormat mDBSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mLastMessageDate"))==null){//.equals("") ||cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mLastMessageDate")).toString()==null){
                mTxtLastMessageDate.setText("");
                mTxtLastMessageLabel.setText("");
            }else{
                mTxtLastMessageDate.setText(mDBSDF.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mLastMessageDate"))).toString());
            }
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is my server date:

```
2015-04-28 12:57:04.000297
```

After using above format i am getting this:

```
Tue Apr 28 12:57:04 GMT+04:00 2015
```

I want the pattern like this:

```
Tuesday, April 28, 2015 1:00 pm
```

Except above `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format even if i am changing "-" to "," it is not working without any error

Comment: use MMM instead of MM

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar i tried it, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) returns a `Date` not a formatted `String`.

Use [SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to format the date and time...

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this base on your requirement.

Input date as string

```
protected String dateFormat(String sqlDate) {
    String strDate = "";
    java.util.Date utilDate;

    SimpleDateFormat sqlDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//input format
    try {
    Calendar calTempDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    calTempDate.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    utilDate = sqlDateFormat.parse(sqlDate);
    calTempDate.setTime(utilDate);
    strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a")
    .format(calTempDate.getTime());//output format
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to find out your solution.

```
SimpleDateFormat fromdateformate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date  date=fromdateformate.parse("2015-04-28 12:57:04.000297");
            SimpleDateFormat todtaeFormate=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM yyyy hh:mm aa");
        String finaldate=   todtaeFormate.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```